# Third-party cookies being blocked inside iFrame in iOS WKWebview

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, webkit, wkwebview

I have a website that is developed in React, in which we have implemented logging in to a third party via an iFrame. This works as expected in all browsers we have to support, except for WKWebview on iOS, which refuses to set cookies on another domain in the iFrame. We have a React Native app that shows the webpage in this webview, so we kinda have to support it..
From a lot of googling around I've found various workarounds that no longer work, and ended up at Webkits bug page: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204109
and this from SalesForce: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351155&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1
It is unclear though whether or not this is actually fixed or if it has been reintroduced (seems like it has, as it's not working on iOS 13.3 devices).
Has anyone had similar experiences, and even better, a potential workaround?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no - though it seems like what I am struggling with is not necessarily a bug, but simply a security feature of Safari that only allows previously visited sites to set cookies.. I've seen some javascript workarounds, but those only work if you control both domains, whereas the site I'm trying to show in the iFrame is a third party site that we are building an integration toward at work

Comment: it looks like it works fine on iOS 13.2.2

Comment: I've tested it on Xcode simulator (iPhone 11 Pro Max iOS 13.3) and it do not work, but on iPhone 8 (iOS 13.3) and iPhone 7 (iOS 11.4.1) cookies in WKWebView works fine, also it works in XCode simulator iPhone 11 Pro Max iOS 13.2.2

Comment: Thanks for testing it out! Seems pretty weird that the behavior is so inconsistent

Comment: Okay so I found a (sort of) workaround for this. So if you control the webview in which you're loading the site hosting the iframe, you can set cookies explicitly through the webviews API on the domain that you are trying to render in the iFrame. For Safari apparently this counts as having visited the site before, so it allows for cross-site cookies to be set in the iFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else running into this issue. I was trying to display a third-party login form in an iframe on a website that I was showing inside a webview, and the cookies from the third-party site were being blocked because Safari only allows third party cookies from sites you have visited before. My workaround ended up being setting cookies on the third party domain directly through the webview API, which apparently "tricks" Safari into thinking the site has been visited before and therefore allowing the cookies.

Comment: @fangmobile Sure, this is what ended up working for us at least (using the CookieManager from the @react-native-community/cookies package): 
`if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
  CookieManager.set(
    {
        name: "SOME_COOKIE_NAME",
        value: "SOME_COOKIE_VALUE",
        path: "/",
        domain: "domain you want to be able to set cookies on inside your webview",
        },
        true
    );
}`

EDIT: sorry for the terrible formatting, I cannot really figure out how to make it properly respect newlines in the code in the comment :/

Comment: does this still work for you? im not able to get this example to work ios 14